# Extract data pairs from a list of associations?

Tags: associations

I am starting to use the new Associations, so this maybe an easy question, but I haven't figured it out. I have a list of associations, like:

```
{<|k1->v1,k2->v2, ..., k3->v3|>, <|q1->w1,q2->w2, ..., q3->w3|>, ...}
```

and I would like to extract a list of data pairs of the form

```
{{v1,v2}, {w1,w2}, ...}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are pure association forms using Part with key names or positions for this.

```
(* Using key names *)
Values[assoc[[All, {"one", "two"}]]]

(* using positions *)
Values[assoc[[All, 1 ;; 2]]]
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work if the keys in the association are arbitrary real numbers

Answer (score 4):

Building an example association:

```
tab = Table[{"one" -> i, "two" -> i^2, "three" -> i^3}, {i, 1, 10}];
```

and

```
assoc = Association @@@ tab;
```

If I understand your question right you are only interested in the first two values, so you can do the following:

```
vals = Values @ tab
```

and

```
Take[#, 2] & /@ vals
```

But if you want to process further on, it might be a good idea to store the information in a dataset `ds = Dataset[assoc]` then you can simply extract the columns you want.